# typescript - conditional paramteres

Tags: typescript, numbers, range

I want to restrict one of the constructor parameter of number type to assign only the values from some range. I know how to archieve similiar effect with setter and conditional statement. I was wondering if there could be a way to create custom type, which is range of numbers, but nowadays there ain't. So, advice me, is it impossible to archieve it by simple maneuver?

Thanks in advance for you replies!
crova

Answer (score 2):

If that range of numbers is relatively low, just list it:

```
type Range1 = 1|2|3|4|5;
var r1: Range1 = 4;
```

If it means something, you can use an enum:

```
const enum Range2 { FirstKind1 = 1, SecondKind2 = 2, ThirdKind = 3 }
var r2a: Range2 = Range2.ThirdKind;
var r2b: Range2 = 3;
```

Otherwise you're out of luck today.

---

I personally would like to be able to declare an `int` type, but even though that's not supported yet, I still diligently annotate my types with an alias, even though it doesn't quite give me any static check today, but makes the intent a bit more readable in the code:

```
type int = number; 

let transactionNo: int;
```

Comment: As I suspected... :/ But your concept with severeal number types is quite nice to me :)